# The max searching algorithm

Tags: max, summarization, post-conditions

Dear Experts and enthusiasts,

I would like to solve the following problem:
I have an array of natural numbers. I would like to find their maximum.

But I have to show my solution with structogram, like that
 http://www.testech-elect.com/pls/images/casetool2.jpg

and I have to do this with midifieing the summation algorithm, this means that I have to midifie the structogram and postcondition  of http://cfhay.inf.elte.hu/~hurrycane/programozas/programming_theorems.pdf

The main horizontal lines have to be kept, but you can modifie everything else. Can you tell me the modified postcondition without recursion? It would be enough. I can make the structogram if I get it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming the only difference between what you're asking for and the algorithm on Exercise 3, is the use of an array, instead of a function *f*. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `C++` code for your algorithm:

```
max = a[0]; ind = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (a[i] > max)
    {
        max = a[i];
        ind = i;
    }
}
```

For the above algorithm, we would have:

1. *StateSpace* = (*a* : N*, *n* : N, *ind* : N, *max* : N)
2. *Pre-condition* = (*a* = *a'* /\ *n* = *length(a)*)
3. *Post-condition* = (*Pre-condition* /\ (*max*, *ind*) = *MAX(i = 0, n) a[ i ]*)